How to handle swagger's default data in C# data model of DataAnnotation properties
I have a C# property model in which properties like FirstName, LastName & Email but I have required validations but when I submit the blank request from the Swagger then default data is coming in request like string in Firstname and Lastname and in Email is user@example.com
So please guide me that how to handle it, so I can test my c# validations.
please guide me that how to handle it?

What swagger tool provides the swagger web page you are presumably talking about?

yes, from where we do the web api testing

From my understanding, you want to set the default json value, so that when post "empty" model in swagger will trigger invalid response. If you have following codes:
    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set;}
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

        [HttpPost]
        public void test(User user)
        {
        }

It will generate and submit defaut value.

You could change the User mode swagger default value by following configuration. Install packageSwashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters
Then implement User model example provider
    public class UserExample : IExamplesProvider<User>
    {
        public User GetExamples()
        {
            return new User
            {
                FirstName = null,
                LastName = null,
                Email = ""

            };
        }
    }

Add below configuration to program.cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.ExampleFilters();  
});
builder.Services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

Then you change the default value to null for name and "" for email which let you receive invalid response when submit.

